# It is really necessary to use Modernizr?

Tags: javascript, feature-detection

Especially if as JS feature detection can i use:

```
if (localStorage in window) { // you have local storage }
```

or even easier:

```
if (crypto.subtle) { // you can encrypt document}
```

And for css detection:

```
if (CSS.supports('display', 'flex')) { // you can load flex layout }
```

Comment: Modernizr is plain JavaScript so you can certainly replicate it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to forget some small things, and to be sure that you don't have problems on any browser, you'd have to test extensively. For instance, the second example (`if (crypto.subtle)`) would fail on some browsers where `crypto` is not defined (`subtle is not a child of undefined`).

So, no, it's not necessary. It's just very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to use Modernizr. Some functionality isn't as easy to detect. Next to that, you don't have to write the checks yourself. Modernizr is a tested, maintained library that helps you detect features.

> Modernizr makes it easy to deliver tiered experiences: make use of the latest and greatest features in browsers which support them, without leaving less fortunate users high and dry.

In short: you don't *have* to use Modernizr (for instance when you want o eliminate any unnecessary libraries or code), but it's sure easy to do so.